# how to send/post JSON in httprequest for windowsphone

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, xmlhttprequest

Hi anyone knows how to send or post JSON httprequest in Windows Phone 7. I used xml httprequest only to send and post with parameters well.

I applied in JSON, it returns an error. Please tell me which one is easier and faster to Windows Phone httprequest whether JSON/XML request. I am going to select the services to develop Windows Phone applications using web services.

```
string postData = "{metaData:{appVersion:1.40},....}"; 
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData); 
postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length); 
postStream.Close(); 

// Start the asynchronous operation to get the response 
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
```

Comment: string postData = "{metaData:{appVersion:1.40},....}"; byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData); postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
            postStream.Close();
            // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);

Comment: how to send httprequest using JSON

Comment: To : Tomalak thanks for arranging the code, i dont know how to arrange. ok thanks

Comment: @CharuLatha - you can use the @<name> format, and the user will get a notification. :)

Comment: Reply me, how to postdata using JSON,if data contains with double quotes like as "{"metaData":{"appUrl" : "http://..","appVersion":"1.4"}

Answer (score 0):

If you have complex json, you can use `RestSharp` to post data and parse responses.

Otherwise, set `Content-type` header: `json/application` to tell a server that it is a json

Comment: yes, i had little complex json, whether xml is better than JSON. I know XML post data and parse responses. But i am not sure which is better in efficiency level for windowsphone

Comment: With xml you can use Linq, and it's better supported by .Net. But use of xml or json is all about your preferences.

Comment: No, I have never had such applications. Sorry